# Is there a way to Find and Replace relative to the project root in SublimeText?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I want to search a certain project subfolder only and exclude certain other ones, so I type in Where:

`/Users/myusername/dev/project/subfolder,-/Users/myusername/dev/project/subfolder/src/*,-/Users/myusername/dev/project/subfolder/huge_sub_subfolder_2/*,-*/images/*`

What I want is to search a project subfolder, with exclusion of certain immediate sub-subfolders (as 'huge_sub_subfolder_2' in the example above).

This is a lot of typing.

is including other first-level subfolders (such as `/Users/myusername/dev/project/huge_subfolder_1`), unless I explicitly type them.

This would be nice to type in Where:

`<projectroot>/subfolder,-<projectroot>/subfolder/huge_subsubfolder/*,-*/images/*`

Even better solution would be to add folder include/exclude patterns to the project file, but I believe currently these do not affect the search results.

Is there a way to specify project root relative include and exclude file/folder patterns - for Find and Replace?